# Definition of stable solutions of elliptic system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider a PDE system
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \Lambda H(u) & \quad\text{in } \Omega, \\
u = 0 & \quad\text{on } \partial\Omega,
\end{cases}
where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m)$ is a given diagonal matrix and $H=(H_1,\ldots,H_m):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a given $C^1$ mapping, $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is the unknown.

In the paper [*rigidity results for stable solutions of symmetric systems*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44841710), the author said that a solution $u$ of the above system is said to be a stable solution if the linearized operator has a positive first eigenvalue.

So what is the linearized operator of the system and what equations does a stable solution satisfy?